# Make kernel detect garmin device

Tags: kernel, usb

I'm trying to connect a usb garmin forerunner device to my system, but the usb device is not detected. I have loaded the following modules:

```
garmin_gps             11544  0 
usbserial              25449  1 garmin_gps
```

But I never see any device detected in neither lsusb nor dmesg when I connect the device. Other USB devices like disks and mp3 players seems to work fine.

I'm unsure how I can continue debugging to find the issue and wonder if someone can guide me?

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the Garmin? Did you try it on another system?

Comment: Good point, but it worked last time I gave it a try on Windows.

Comment: Can you change the mode on the Garmin device? Sometimes the USB port can play multiple roles and you have to set whether you are connecting it to a PC or using it to connect an add-on device or whatever.